# Third-party UI library [using styled-components] + Next.js SSR CSS rules ordering/specificity issue

Tags: user-interface, next.js, styled-components, server-side-rendering

I have a third-party library that uses styled-components v5.3.6

I am using this UI library in my Next-JS app. My Next-JS app also has styled-components v5.3.6 as a dependency, using which i overwrite styling for my UI components.

> For instance, i have a component in my UI-library as :

```
const Header = (props) => { 
    return (
           <Text p="0 14px" {...props}/>
         );
}
```

> Usage in my main-app

For my requirement , i require padding of 4px on right and left. So, i created a styled.ts file and  i have overwritten the  component

> mystyled.styled.ts

```
import styled from "styled-components";


export const ModifiedTextComponent = styled(Text)`
  padding: 0 4px;
`


> someComponent.ts


import modifiedTextComponent from './mystyled.styled.ts';


function test() {
  return <ModifiedTextComponent> Text </ModifiedTextComponent>
}



Issue


On SSR, css-specificity for this component changes. Styling defined in <ModifiedTextComponent /> takes less priority over styling of my Text Component.

So during SSR, my ModifiedTextComponent always ends up with a padding of '14px' instead of `4px` on left and right-side.


Note, for this query, naming my third-party UI library as `MyLib`
```

What i tried.

To resolve this, i removed styled-components dependencies from my main-app and exposed styled utility from my third-party library

> Third-party library

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export {styled}
```

> main-app > mystyled.styled.ts

```
import {styled} from "MyLib";

export const ModifiedTextComponent = styled(Text)`
  padding: 0 4px;
`
```

Exposing styled utility from my third-party library i.e MyLib and consuming it directly seems to resolve the issue.

But this creates an extra dependency on my UI library. I would like to know if there is some other way to resolve this. Also, wanted to understand why specificity for my third party library is high over css-styling that i add in my app.

Solution - 2 , suggested by styled-components-library

https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity

Please suggest if someone has a better solution to this, or an explanation to why CSS specificity gets affected with NextJS SSR and Styled-components.